# How to review a first post correctly when getting "Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully"?

Tags: support, review

When I am trying to review a first post, I get:

*Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully*

**NB** : The post does not contain any codes or urls.

How to review it correctly?

Comment: Could you show us the post in question please?

Comment: @terdon http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/289956/xubuntu-live-running-from-5gb-usb-but-free-space-only-800mb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would depend on the post, naturally, but I assume you're talking about [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/145913). That post looks perfectly fine, so you would choose "No Action Needed" (as another reviewer already has). If you're not sure you can always choose "Skip"